# apache not starting undefined symbol: proxy_hook_canon_handler

Tags: apache, undefined, symbols

Apache httpd is not starting. This is the first time I tried to start it on this particular server. I am getting the following error.

> httpd: Syntax error on line 38 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax
>   error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/proxy_connect.load:
>   Cannot load modules/mod_proxy_connect.so into server:
>   /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_connect.so: undefined symbol:
>   proxy_hook_canon_handler

OS: RHEL 7.3

httpd:  2.4.6-40.el7_2.4.x86_64

apr-1.4.8-3.el7.x86_64

apr-util-1.5.2-6.el7.x86_64

**httpd.conf**

```
 Security
ServerTokens OS
ServerSignature On
TraceEnable On

ServerName "servername"
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
PidFile run/httpd.pid
Timeout 120
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
LimitRequestFieldSize 8190


User apache
Group apache

AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>


HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog "/opt/www_logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn
EnableSendfile On

#Listen 80


Include "/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/*.load"
Include "/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/*.conf"
Include "/etc/httpd/conf/ports.conf"

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" forwarded
```

**/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d**

```
authz_core.load
authz_host.load
dir.load
filter.load
log_config.load
mime.conf
mime.load
prefork.conf
prefork.load
proxy_connect.load
proxy_html.load
rewrite.load
ssl.load
systemd.load
unixd.load
xml2enc.load
```

Comment: Looks like that proxy module has been compiled against a different version of the http server. You want to check your package sources or update the packages.

Comment: this is the version of the proxy module mod_proxy_html.x86_64            1:2.4.6-40.el7_2.4

Comment: That comment does not really answer the suggestions I made...

Comment: Also take a look here: https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7002562

Answer (score 0):

The `proxy_connect` and `proxy_html` modules depend on the base `proxy` module, so make sure that's loaded too.  There isn't a `proxy.load` file in the list of config files you mention so that may well be the problem.